How to use a custom domain for auth redirect with AWS Amplify Gen 2
I've added a custom domain to my Cognito User Pool so that when users attempt a sign in with Google they do not see a shady looking link. So when calling signInWithRedirect({ provider: 'Google' }) the user should be sent to my domain not the default one from the User Pool. How can I achieve that?
Basically I need to change the auth.oauth.domain property from the generated outputs.json by Amplify.
